# How to apply MathJax/KaTex to render a React component

Tags: reactjs, mathjax, react-component, katex, slatejs

I am making a web editor using React & SlateJS. There are LaTex code in the editor content and I want the user to see the rendered LaTex equations. MathJax and [KaTex](https://katex.org/docs/autorender.html) have auto-rendering feature by loading them as CDNs. Once they are loaded, the content on html body is rendered. But they are not live-rendering when I modify the content.

So I have made a button that opens a [modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) which renders the un-editable edior content in a smaller window, and I want the LaTex codes to be rendered in the modal.

The `APP` component:

```
import {Editor} from 'slate-react';
import ReactModel from 'react-modal';
import RenderedEditorDialog from "./RenderedEditorDialog";

class APP extends React.component {

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"editorContainer"}>
                <div className={"editor"}>
                    <Editor
                        autoFocus
                        ref={this.ref}
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
                        renderMark={this.renderMarks}
                        renderBlock={this.renderBlock}
                    />
                </div>
                <ReactModal
                    isOpen={this.state.showMathDialog}
                    contentLabel="Rendered content"
                    onRequestClose={this.handleCloseMathDialog}
                >
                    <button onClick={this.handleCloseMathDialog}>Close Dialog</button>
                    <RenderedEditorDialog value={this.state.value}/>
                </ReactModal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

`RenderedEditorDialog` (modal) component:

```
import {Editor} from 'slate-react';

class RenderedEditorDialog extends React.Component {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-constructor
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Editor
                    value={this.props.value}
                    renderMark={this.renderMarks}
                    renderBlock={this.renderBlock}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My question is how I can apply MathJax/KaTex to render the content in `RenderedEditorDialog` component?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

KaTeX can be applied to individual DOM elements on demand, instead of all at once, by calling [`renderMathInElement`](https://katex.org/docs/autorender.html) when desired.  Calling this from `componentDidUpdate` should do the trick:

```js
import {Editor} from 'slate-react';

class RenderedEditorDialog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.ref}>
                <Editor
                    value={this.props.value}
                    renderMark={this.renderMarks}
                    renderBlock={this.renderBlock}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        renderMathInElement(this.ref.current, katexOptions);
    }
}
```

I'm more comfortable with hook-based components instead of classes, which would look like this:

```js
function RenderedEditorDialog(props) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        renderMathInElement(ref.current, katexOptions);
    });
    return (
        <div ref={ref}>
            <Editor
                value={props.value}
                renderMark={props.renderMarks}
                renderBlock={props.renderBlock}/>
        </div>
    )
};
```

I'm not sure whether you want this on `RenderedEditorDialog` or another more specific component, but this should give you the idea.  For speed, you want to apply `renderMathInElement` to the smallest container that contains the updated math.